# Gráficos highcharts plotagem das datas quais são os valores validos para o mes

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, highcharts, gráfico

Estou plotando um gráfico do qual a entrada das datas não conferem com a plotagem.
Exemplo quando entro com a informação da data 10/12/2017 ele plota como (10 de janeiro de 2017) como corrigir isso?

O carregamento é feito através do banco de dados o código usado:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function (data) {

    Highcharts.chart('container-grafico1', {
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperaturas Registradas'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                'Clique e selicione a area do grafico que deseja dar o zoom': 'Clique e selicione a area do grafico que deseja dar o zoom'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperaturas em Graus Celsius'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 2
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'temperatura da água',
            data: [
    {% for i in temperatura_db %}
     [Date.UTC({{ i[2].split('-')|join(', ') }}, {{ i[3].split(':')|join(', ') }}),{{i[1]|safe}}],
    {% endfor %}
         ]
        }]
    });

});
</script>
```

```html
    <div class="container">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center"style="color:white">
  <div><h1> Graficos </h1></div> 
  
  <div>
  <form>
   <div id="container-grafico1"></div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Corrigido publicação..

Comment: tente definir o que vem do banco como um string no js um (cast).
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

Comment: Kaue Arima   as declarações do js são essas?! var json = {};
   json.chart = chart;
   json.title = title;
   json.subtitle = subtitle;
   json.tooltip = tooltip;
   json.xAxis = xAxis;
   json.yAxis = yAxis;  
   json.series = series;
   json.plotOptions = plotOptions;
   $('#container-grafico1').highcharts(json);

Comment: Não estou  sabendo em qual parte do código devo mexer para resolver este problema!

Answer (score -1):

Preciso ver o codigo inteiro, mas quando tive esse problema eu fiz assim:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

title: {
    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
},

yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Number of Employees'
    },
    categorias: [ String('10/01/03'),...]
},...
```

Comment: como eu faço para aparecer o código conforme vc mostrou no comentário anterior?

Comment: tem que ter alguma tag antes e depois ?! qual tag devo usar para mostrar o código formatado igual o seu?